# Why does my script omit leading whitespace in console output?

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function consoleWriteLine() {
  echo $* >&2
}

consoleWriteLine "    indented by 4 spaces"
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
$ ./test.sh
indented by 4 spaces
```

Where did my 4 spaces go? And how do I get them back?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just quote the `echo` in your function:

```
function consoleWriteLine() {
  echo "$*" >&2
}
```

`echo` just notices multiple arguments separated by space and prints them separated by a *single* space. See:

```
$ echo a b c
a b c
$ echo a b             c
a b c
$ echo "a b             c"
a b             c
```

In the last example the string `a b             c` is **one** single argument and `echo`ed as it is.

Comment: The key for me to understand here was, quoting the argument initially will only preserve the whitespace until it is passed into `consoleWriteLine`. The second time it is `echo`'d, the whitespace needs to be preserved again by additional quotes. I would have never guessed that you can put quotes around `$*`.

Comment: Not only can you put quotes around `$*`, the variant `$@` was specifically created to expand into *separate words* when quoted: `"$@"` can be several arguments, `"$*"` is always just one. `echo` is one of the few commands where it makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem myself,

As per [This blog](https://logbuffer.wordpress.com/2010/09/23/bash-scripting-preserve-whitespaces-in-variables/) you need to change the IFS as by default it contains white space and so sees "xxx yyy     zzzz" as 3 strings with white space between them.

`IFS='\n'`

prior to the command will fix it, and unset IFS to remove the change

`unset IFS`

Comment: this is working, but the accepted solution (adding quotes) is much neater.

Comment: Nod, I didn't notice it wasn't quoted. Whoops! :D